# Advice for creating components for menu options

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material2

I'm working with Angular 4 and Angular Material 2. I would like some advice for creating components of each menu option. My menu has 4 categories and each of them has 5 subcategories. The content are applications. I have to display the applications according to the category and subcategory.
The content of the categories should look like this mock-up. It has sections (new software, last added, subcategory 1, subcategory 2 and so...)

Category content

[image]

The subcategories have the content like the follow mock-up. Just a list of apps

Subcategory content

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also creating a shopping cart application. Below is a snapshot of my electronics category. I do NOT know if this is an approach you are looking for but this is how I designed my electronics category. Of course, my app has many categories, electronics - sub (computers, cell phones, smart watches), toys (dolls, princess), etc.. At the top, I have carousel which shows all the categories, next shows you all the categories, next are the brands in electronics, and products in electronics. When I search for electronics, I get it's 'params[id] and passed it to as input,

```
"carousel - shows different categories"
<category [input]="search"></category>,
<brands [input]="search"></brands> ,and 
<products [input]="search></products>.
```

Category and brands have their own classes so I know how to search for them or show them or not.

```
export class Category {
  constructor(
    public name: string, 
    public imageUrl: string,
    public title?: string,
    public isFeatured?: boolean,
    public categoryId?: string) {}
}
```

[image]

For your information, YES. I use reusable components through out my application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm creating a disability application store. Did it work with reusable components? I want to know if I can use ngif in order to display the apps according to the category and subcategory. For example: <div *ngIf="application.category ==='Autism' && application.subcategory ==='Language'; then thenBlock else elseBlock"> </div>

Comment: @Steph yeah I'm sure you can use `ngIf` to determine what should be rendered.  Either way create a new project and test the above out and go from there.

Comment: I am using mongo Db so when I want to search for google cell phones (has a brand and category). router.post('/brand-category', function(req, res, next) {
 var brand = req.body.brand;
 var category = req.body.category;
 Product.find({'brand': brand, 'category': category }). This way, In my front-end, I get all products in cell phones but with google only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One last question did u make a component for each category and brand?

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning angular but for my app to be realistic, my app has a tree structure. Each Brand and category has its own routing, which means they have their own header, home, home details. For my apple site, below shoes the routing module:

```
// Define the routes
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'apple', component: AppleComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'h/apple', component: AppleAccessoryComponent },
      { path: 'iwatch', component: IwatchComponent },
      { path: 'about iphone', component: IphoneAboutComponent},
      { path: 'iphone', component: IphoneComponent },
      { path: 'apple about', component: AppleAboutComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: AppleDetailComponent },
      { path: '', component: AppleHomeComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

Below is a snapshot of my apple component. You do not mind voting my answer?

[image]